# How to save a session in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, save

For example, **I have**

```
Session["PatientName"] = patientNameTextBox.Text;
```

After information is entered into the `textbox`, a button will be clicked to save the session but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :).

Comment: Your above code would save the text in the session , what do you mean by saving ? are you having problem in retrieving the value or do you want to save that in persistent storage

Comment: your session is good to go

Comment: @Habib: How are you going so far?

Comment: @MartinMulder, not bad .... ??

Answer (score 3):

If you place the code against Button_Click event, then the above line `Session["PatientName"] = patientNameTextBox.Text;` would save the `Text` value in the session. To retrieve it back you can do:

```
string patientName = Session["PatientName"] != null ? Session["PatientName"].ToString() 
                                                     : ""; //or null
```

Remember not to store too much information in sessions, since they are maintained on server for each user.

Comment: Can be simplified into `string parientName = Session["PatientName"] ?? "";`. That is if you want to avoid null in the first place.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, yes, null coalescing operator can be used as well. Thanks

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure this is answering his question. Now he has the data in a variable, but I'm getting the feeling that he already knew how to do that (with all of it's complexity..) - he wants to save it somehow. The wanted saving fashion is vague, however.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, I guess the OP was having problem in retrieving the value, hence saying its not saved. But I will ask to clarify

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I understand a little better now. May I ask how I would put the information from this session displayed in a label?

Comment: @Carrie, you can do `yourlabel.Text = patientName";` that will display the retrieved patient name from the session, in label.

Comment: @MartinMulder, I didn't had that before comment from Yorye, should have tested it in VS. Thanks for pointing it out, Its now removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value is inside the Session by doing this:

```
if (Session["PatientName"] != null) 
    ...
```

You can retrieve the value by doing this:

```
// Remember to cast it to the correct type, because Session only returns objects.
string patientName = (string)Session["PatientName"];
```

If you are not sure if there is a value inside and you want a default value, try this:

```
// Once again you have to cast. Use operator ?? to optionally use the default value.
string patientName = (string)Session["PatientName"] ?? "MyDefaultPatientName";
```

To put your answer back in a textbox or label:

```
patientLabel.Text = patientName;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can save a session when a button is clicked:**

```
protected void buttonSaveSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string patientName = textBoxPatientName.Text;
    Session["PatientName"] = patientName;
}
```

**This is how you can check or someone has a session:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["PatientName"] != null)
    {
        //Your Method()
    }
}
```